# Books for programming environments/interfaces of distributed systems?

Tags: textbook

I found that Advanced Programming Unix Environment and The Linux Programming Interface provide specific programming knowledge to me, compared to the concepts introduced in OS text books such as the dinosaur book Operating System Concepts.

Are there equivalences for distributed systems:

- books for programming environments/interfaces of distributed systems (either for specific interface, or better yet, some abstract interface)?
- books for concepts of distributed systems? (Are Courloris' book and Tanenbaum's book the best books available?)

Thanks.